# Failed to convert string to int error when upserting data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We want to upsert a record when a person is directed to one of our landing pages, but the page errors out due to a string not converting to an int. We've tried setting the var and they still cause the issue to happen. Any ideas?

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html class="no-js" lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <title>TITEL</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://image.s6.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9713707565077471/m/1/foundation.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://image.s6.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9713707565077471/m/1/custom.css">
 <script src="http://image.s6.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9713707565077471/m/1/modernizr.js">   </script>
</head>

%%[

Set @DELookUp = "b_patient_data"

Set @apptid = RequestParameter("pid")
Set @familyid = RequestParameter("fid")
Set @HOHid = RequestParameter('hid')




Set @GroupRecords = LookupOrderedRows(@DELookUp,0,"HOHID","Subscriber Key",@HOHid)

If Rowcount(@GroupRecords) > 0 THEN 

for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@GroupRecords) do 

Set @row = Row(@GroupRecords,@i)

Set @ClinicID = Lookup("b_appointment_data","ClinicID","ClinicID",@apptid )
Set @PatientID = Field(@row,"Subscriber Key")
Set @DoNotText = "0"
Set @DoNotContact = Field(@row,"DoNotContact")
Set @HoHFirstName = Field(@row,"HoHFirstName")
Set @HoHLastName = Field(@row,"HoHLastName")
Set @PrimaryPhoneAreaCode = Field(@row,"PrimaryPhoneAreaCode")
Set @PrimaryPhoneNumber = Field(@row,"PrimaryPhoneNumber")
Set @PrimaryPhoneType = Field(@row,"PrimaryPhoneType")
Set @SecondaryPhoneAreaCode = Field(@row,"SecondaryPhoneAreaCode")
Set @SecondaryPhoneNumber = Field(@row,"SecondaryPhoneNumber")
Set @SecondaryPhoneType = Field(@row,"SecondaryPhoneType")
Set @curDate = Now()
Set @ClinicName = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","FacilityName","CRMFacilityID",@ClinicID)
Set @ClinicAddress1 = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","Address1","CRMFacilityID",@ClinicID)
Set @ClinicPhoneNumber = Format(Lookup("ll_clinic_data","WebsiteNumber","CRMFacilityID",@ClinicID) ,"###-###-####")
Set @ClinicCity = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","City","CRMFacilityID",@ClinicID)
Set @ClinicState = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","State","CRMFacilityID",@ClinicID)
Set @ClinicZip = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","Zip","CRMFacilityID",@ClinicID)

If @PrimaryPhoneType == "Mobile" Then
    Set @PhoneNumber = Concat("1",@PrimaryPhoneAreaCode,@PrimaryPhoneNumber)
    Set @MaskedPhoneNumber = Concat("xxx-xxx-",Substring(@PhoneNumber,8,4))
Else
    Set @PhoneNumber = Concat("1",@SecondaryPhoneAreaCode,@SecondaryPhoneNumber) 
    Set @MaskedPhoneNumber = Concat("xxx-xxx-",Substring(@PhoneNumber,8,4))
EndIf


UPSERTDATA(
"LL_Test_SMS_OptIn_LandingPage",1,
"HoHID",@HoHID,
"Phone",@PhoneNumber,
"PatientID",@PatientID,
"DoNotText",@DoNotText,
"DoNotContact",@DoNotContact,
"HoHFirstName",@HoHFirstName,
"HoHLastName",@HoHLastName,
"ClinicID",@ClinicID,
"SMS_Opt_In","Y",
"Opt_In_Date",@curDate,
"SMS_MO_Opt_In_Date",@curDate,
"Update_Date",@curDate,
"SubscriberKey",@PhoneNumber)


Next @i

ENDIF
]%%

 <body>

  <section>
      <article>
         <header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <img src="http://image.s6.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9713707565077471/m/1/KSMlogo.png" border="0" alt="">
                    <span class="right">Opt-in <br>to SMS <br>Reminders</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </article>
   </section>
```

Comment: Which of the LL_Test_SMS_OptIn_LandingPage columns are numbers?

Comment: Does the phone number string you're retrieving and updating follow the guidelines for Phone datatype (assuming the DE column is of that type)?  

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/data_types/

Comment: HOHID, PatientID, ClinicID, DoNotText are all numbers. The phone number follows the referenced guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ClinicID value was actually the culprit. Once we changed the value for ClinicID we were able to upsert successfully.

Comment: Sweet.  If you could mark your question as answered, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck adding numeric characters to zero in order for it to be read as a number.

```
Set @var = TEXTVALUE
Set @var = Add(@var,0)
```

Comment: No dice. Still the same error.

Comment: Is the @DoNotText variable the value you are trying to push as an int?

Comment: Haven't been able to figure out which variable it is that is causing the issue. I've tried debugging each individual value and still find that the error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment out your Upsert and in it's place display all of the variable values on the page to determine which one is causing the datatype mismatch.

Without seeing the data, the `@DoNotText` value may be the culprit as [@edu8rdo](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/7711/edu8rdo) suggested.  You're setting it to a string and then writing it to a Number DE column.

Something like this:

```
/*
UPSERTDATA(
"LL_Test_SMS_OptIn_LandingPage",1,
"HoHID",@HoHID,
"Phone",@PhoneNumber,
"PatientID",@PatientID,
"DoNotText",@DoNotText,
"DoNotContact",@DoNotContact,
"HoHFirstName",@HoHFirstName,
"HoHLastName",@HoHLastName,
"ClinicID",@ClinicID,
"SMS_Opt_In","Y",
"Opt_In_Date",@curDate,
"SMS_MO_Opt_In_Date",@curDate,
"Update_Date",@curDate,
"SubscriberKey",@PhoneNumber)
*/
outputline(concat("<br>HoHID: ",@HoHID))
outputline(concat("<br>Phone: ",@PhoneNumber))
outputline(concat("<br>PatientID: ",@PatientID))
outputline(concat("<br>DoNotText: ",@DoNotText))
outputline(concat("<br>DoNotContact: ",@DoNotContact))
outputline(concat("<br>HoHFirstName: ",@HoHFirstName))
outputline(concat("<br>HoHLastName: ",@HoHLastName))
outputline(concat("<br>ClinicID: ",@ClinicID))
outputline(concat("<br>SMS_Opt_In: ","Y"))
outputline(concat("<br>Opt_In_Date: ",@curDate))
outputline(concat("<br>SMS_MO_Opt_In_Date: ",@curDate))
outputline(concat("<br>Update_Date: ",@curDate))
outputline(concat("<br>SubscriberKey: ",@PhoneNumber))
```

For reference:
[**AMPScript Utility Functions**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/)

Comment: Yep! This is exactly what I'm thinking the issue is. Make the "0" an actual number (sans quotes).